# Dropbox metadata to JSON with python

Tags: python, json, dropbox

I am trying to output the metadata of some files in my dropbox in json format, using the below.

```
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder(path = '/TG/').entries:
    print(entry.name)
    path = ("/TG/" + str(entry.name))
    data_output = {dbx.files_get_metadata(path=path)}

    if '.py' in path:
        print(data_output)

        with open(write_file, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(data_output, outfile)
```

It's outputting TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable however.

Comment: Why *is* data_output a single-element set?

Comment: I thought that being in a for loop would make it multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Via the use of `{` and `}`, you're putting the result of the [`files_get_metadata`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_get_metadata) call into a `set`, which is not JSON serializable. There doesn't seem to be any need for a set here in the code you shared, so you can just drop the `{` and `}`. That would leave the actual `FileMetadata` type, though that's not actually JSON serializable either. You'll need to convert that to something that makes sense for your use case. E.g., most simply, just call `str` on it.

Additionally, as written, your code is a bit redundant. The [`files_list_folder`](https://dropbox-sdk-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dropbox.html#dropbox.dropbox.Dropbox.files_list_folder) method already gives you the same information you would get from `files_get_metadata`, so you can drop the `files_get_metadata` calls. The `files_list_folder` method returns a list of the same `Metadata` objects that `files_get_metadata` returns. (Removing the `files_get_metadata` calls should make your code run faster too.)

Also, you can get the path directly from the entry without reconstructing it.

With all of those changes, it would look like:

```
for entry in dbx.files_list_folder(path = '/TG/').entries:
    print(entry.name)

    if '.py' in entry.path_lower:
        print(entry)

        with open(write_file, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(str(entry), outfile)  # or whatever conversion or formatting you want instead of just str
```